# SDF file creation for window mobile 6.5

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile-6.5, sdf

I create a vs 2005 project and a sdf file using ms sql server express 2005. And I try to connect it in MC65. I got this error

> The database file has been created by
>   an earlier version of SQL Server
>   Compact. Please upgrade using
>   SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works. I create sdf by using ms sql server express 2008. In Window Mobile, I wonder there is no backward compatible. Is it like that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim engine As SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeEngine("Data Source=" & Path & SDFfileName)

engine.Upgrade("Data Source=" & Path & SDFfileName & ";")
```